# which ide (android development) is suitable for measuring sound in decibels?

Tags: android, ide

I want to make an android app which receives sound from the microphone of the smartphone and converts the value to decibels. I am completely new to android development, so have no idea about which IDE or platform to use for this.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of android studio from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjw3MPNBRDjARIsAOYU6x_lIVSdfPkpCmb7aYZL4tD9uV-OaZM3MhxQmdbewhhf_4YnQ3yGWPwaAqw4EALw_wcB#mac-bundle)

This answer may not be enough for you as you still need to know a couple of things to start building reasonable android applications. Good luck with that!